# using the pygame: [spritesheet].subsurface function, is there a way to draw the sprite from the bottom rather than the top left corner

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a set of sprites, also on a spritesheet, which bounces slightly up and down, so the sprite height changes slightly.
By coding: ***spritesheet.subsurface(x, y, width, height***), it will draw the sprite starting from (x, y) and then the width and height to the right and down respectively, however, when drawing the frames from the same screen-relative position, the sprite looks like the feet are moving down and up.
So that, if I had positioned frame 1 of the sprite to have the feet touching the floor, frame 2 would have the feet through the floor.

Is there a way to draw the sprite, say, from the bottom left, or bottom centre?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) uses a rectangular area to create a new surface that references its parent. The origin (0, 0) of the pygame coordinate system is the top left. This cannot be changed.

However, if you know the bottom left coordinate (`left_x`, `bottom_y`) of a *sprit* on a *spritsheet* the rectangle of the *sprite* can be computed (`spritesheet` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) object):

```py
sheet_height = spritsheet.get_height()
sprite = spritsheet.subsurface((left_x, sheet_height - bottom_y - height, width, height))
```

The code can be made more comprehensible with a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

```py
sheet_height = spritsheet.get_height()

sprite_rect = pygame.Rect(left_x, 0, height, height)
sprite_rect.bottom = sheet_height - bottom_y 

sprite = spritsheet.subsurface(sprite_rect )
```